# Localization due to pods integrated in project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, localization, cocoapods

I've an app only for English language which is using cocoa pods. Now some of the pod have localisation in them. Due to those localisation's files there are many languages apart from English on App Store page of my app. How can I remove these languages from App Store and keep using those pods?

Comment: Can you please provide details about your requirements?

Comment: @Rohan There is a library called PSUpdateApp on cocoacontrols.com. That library is localised in languages like Arabic, German etc. Now due these localisation my app also shows these languages on app store page. I Just want to show English language on app store page.

Comment: Thanks for the details.. You can remove(deselect) unwanted languages in the iTunes App setting page.